# Document-based-like application + updating fields/menus/etc when switching document?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-bindings, documents, document-based

I have an application with multiple documents opened at once (as different tabs), but not implemented the Cocoa way, with `NSDocument` etc

So, let's say, that application is a text editor : *e.g. an NSTextView in each document/tab and a menu (in the `MainMenu`) with options (on/off) related to that particular document.*

**Scenarios :**

- The user clicks a menu item (option) and the option is applied to the
  current tab
- Now, the user switches tab and the options (of the menu) should be update according to current document's settings

How should I go about that in the most Cocoa-friendly way?

*(I certainly CAN do it; though I'm interested in what could be a more efficient way (and my definitely isn't))*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [validateUserInterfaceItem:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSUserInterfaceValidations_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) on NSDocument. Menu and toolbar items call it to check if they should be enabled or not. Read about [Implementing Validation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UIValidation/Articles/implementingValidation.html) in general and [Enabling Menu Items](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MenuList/Articles/EnablingMenuItems.html) specifically.